# Simple tag searching with Sphinx

Tags: sql, postgresql, sphinx

For example, I have 3 tables:

```
documents (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    title character varying(256),
    content text,
    created timestamp with time zone
);

tags (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    tag_content character varying(128)
);

tag_assoc (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    document_id integer,
    tag_id integer
);
```

I would like to be able to search `documents` for `title`, `content`, and for tags.

My `sql_query` so far is very simple like:

```
sql_query SELECT id, title, content FROM documents
```

How would I set up the Sphinx sql_query so that the tags associated with each document are joined to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use inside sql_query a subselect with group_concat to retrieve them , but a better approach would be to use the s`ql_joined_field`.  In your case, would look like:

```
sql_joined_field = tags from query; tag.assoc.document_id, \
                   tag_content from tags join tag_assoc on \
                   tags.id=tar_assoc.tag_id order by tag.assoc.document_id asc
```

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly so far, although I had to change it to this to make it work:

`sql_joined_field = tags from query; tag_assoc.document_id, tag_content from tags join tag_assoc on tags.id=tar_assoc.tag_id order by tag_assoc.document_id asc`